# MYSQL statement issues please point out

Tags: mysql, sql

```
 IF EXISTS(select * from person_data where `Key`='tags' and `Value`='blogger')
    begin  
    UPDATE person_data SET `Value`= 'aaaaaaa'
    end 
    else 
    begin
    INSERT INTO person_data(Id,`Key`,`Value`,Person_id)
    SELECT IFNULL(MAX(Id)+1,1),'aaa','bbb',1 FROM person_data
    end if;
```

it keeps complain there is an issue in line 1.
please point out where I did wrong

Comment: error :Error code 1064, SQL state 42000: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF EXISTS(select * from person_data where `Key`='tags' and `Value`='blogger')
be' at line 1

Comment: You need to put your column KEY in back ticks (``) as KEY is a Keyword in MySQL

Answer (score 0):

Change `END IF` to `END`, that should do it.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating SP, have a look at below

You need to put your column `KEY` in back ticks (``) as **KEY** is a Keyword in MySQL

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE
    PROCEDURE `InsertOrUpdate`()
    BEGIN

    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO ifexists FROM person_data WHERE KEY='tags' AND VALUE='blogger';

    IF ifexists !=0 THEN
        UPDATE person_data SET VALUE= 'aaaaaaa';
    ELSE
        INSERT INTO person_data(Id,KEY,VALUE,Person_id) 
        SELECT IFNULL(MAX(Id)+1,1),'aaa','bbb',1 
        FROM person_data ;
    END IF;
    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use IF control block OUTSIDE of functions. So that affects both of your queries.

Turn the EXISTS clause into a subquery instead within an IF function

```
SELECT IF( EXISTS(
         select * from person_data where `Key`='tags' and `Value`='blogger'), true, false)
```